# Failed to connect to EC2 even security group is correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance, when ssh to it, it says " debug1: Connection established." , then hangs there and time out. I can also telnet to it with port 22. That mean the server is reachable, and security group is correct, right? but why ssh times out?

```
 ssh -i "devops.pem" ec2-user@ec2-3-91-100-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com -vvvv
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/test/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/test/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/test/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/test/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/Users/test/.ssh/master-ec2-user@ec2-3-91-100-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-91-100-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file devops.pem type -1
debug1: identity file devops.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
```

Answer (score 0):

It's blocked by firewall. When fixed the firewall, the connection is good.